# Foreach - Different instructions depending on the type of items in List<FooBar>

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have an interface class `FooBar` and two concrete classes, `Foo` and `Bar`.

If I `foreach` in `FooBar`, how can I use a different instruction set depending on whether my item is a `Foo` or a `Bar` ? (for example, because `Foo` and `Bar` don't have the same properties).

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Comment: I'd like to add that this sounds like you are doing something wrong. Most likely you should have a method in the interface that is overriden in the classes that implement it

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about. Do you wanto to have both Foo and Bar a method with the same name but with different implementations? Or do you want to call methods with different names (like `Foo.OneMethodName()` and `Bar.CompletelyDifferentMethodName()`)?

Comment: In a more concrete case, if you have Foo and Bar instances in the same list, each class with different properties, i want to give these properties to another object (a framework object i can't modify). Problem is, instantiating this another object needs context data (URLs, etc...) that aren't supposed to be known by FooBar objects (if i wasn't the case, i would create the item with an override method of FooBar interface)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three options.

If possible, `Foo` and `Bar` should have a common base class `FooBarBase` -- or implement a common interface, your `FooBar` -- which defines some virtual method, say `DoStuff()`. `Foo` and `Bar` each implement `DoStuff()` appropriately.

Since you've already got an interface, you're basically there.

```
public interface FooBar {
    void DoStuff(SomeFrameworkThing x);
}
```

...

```
List<FooBar> myFooAndBarList = new myFooAndBarList() { ... };

var thing = new SomeFrameworkThing(/* long list of murky parameters, all different */);

foreach (var fb in myFooAndBarList) {
    fb.DoStuff(thing);
}
```

But if that's not possible, or if the particular details of what you're doing render it painfully complicated (e.g., you want to make them do totally unrelated stuff), you can do it like this. Just looking at the code, you can see why the above version is preferred. In C#7, there's nicer syntax for this, but I don't have that installed yet to test with (1).

```
foreach (var o in myFooAndBarList) {
    if (o is Foo) {
        var f = o as Foo;
        f.FooMethod();
        f.FooProperty = "lol";
    }
    else if (o is Bar) {
        var b = o as Bar;
        b.BarMethod(234, 345);
        b.BarProp = new Dictionary<Foo, List<Bar>>();
    }
}
```

Then finally, you can do it the weird, esoteric, bizarre way, with `dynamic`:

```
public void DoStuff(Foo f) {
    //  stuff
}

public void DoStuff(Bar b) {
    //  other stuff
}
```

...

```
foreach (dynamic d in myFoAndBarList) {
    DoStuff(d);
}
```

[Try it. I'm not pulling your leg.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4rccKT) I don't recommend this method; I recommend the first method, or maybe the second if you're stuck with it.

(1) I've sitting here watching the Visual Studio installer for an hour. At the moment, the status text says "NO SYNTAX FOR YOU".

Comment: Using late binding is certainly an option but I would look at the traditional OOP methods first, and only if they're not suitable resort to more esoteric ones... Not a harsh critique, just an observation. This can fail in interesting ways when you add another implementation later, whereas moving the methods to the interface and implementing it differently would prevent it and guide implementors on the path to success.

Comment: @EdPlunkett the first variant looks better with the latest edition of C#:
`foreach (var o in myFooAndBarList)
    switch(o)
    {
            case Foo fo:
            fo.FooMethod();
            break;
            case Bar bo:
            bo.BarMethod();
            break;
            default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
            break;
    }
  `

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov Yeah, I thought of that. I've been sitting here for the last hour watching the VS installer tell me I can't have C#7 to test it with yet.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yeap, in my personal experience, new installer can take quite a lot of time in comparison with older VS installers if you need a few development chains installed.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I can't do `fb.DoStuff();` because the DoStuff needs data that should be unknown to  fb. The solution if o is Foo may be problematic if I decide to add more classes implementing FooBar interface in the future (will be a bigger and bigger if).

Comment: @YthioCsi Do all the DoStuff() methods need arbitrarily different inputs, or do they all work on the same thing? If the latter, that's a parameter or parameters. Looking at your most recent comment on the question, I would say: Caller creates framework object with URLs etc., passes it to `public virtual X DoStuff(SomeFrameworkClass obj)` -- where X may just be `void`. If the former, your logic can't be generalized. You could write a DoStuff() overload that takes every possible parameter -- but then you might need a new one down the road.

Comment: @EdPlunkett My case is the later and I ended up doing what you suggest in this comment. However I keep having the feeling that i breached the Single Responsibility Principle. Now my IRecords implementations hold states after queries but also initialize a framework object :(

Comment: @YthioCsi You'll have to provide more information about what state is being held by whom, and what `IRecord` is. Can you add a more complete sample to your question, one that illustrates these concerns?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Basically it's a `Query` class family to do DB queries, a IRecord family to hold Query results and a IRecordBuilder because it's not `Query` role to build Records so builder pattern. When i want to update my DB, Ineed a framework object with an `Update` method, instantiated with table name, etc... before receiving IRecord properties `frameworkItem["columnName"] = record.property1`. This is why I feel like doing the initialization of framework item in IRecord implementation is against Single Responsibility. I also don't like to instantiate in a method and initialize in another class

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry i didn't remember i used placeholder names here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm at work, I don't have the time to deduce which of those terms matches which of your placeholders, and then translate it all into code.